# scrolltop() doesn't work with window

Tags: jquery

I tried to do this simple function, but this doesn't work.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() > 2000){
        $('.edicao-anos').css({"display": "block"});
    };
});
```

This is a basic scroll top, if the scroll to the top is bigger than 2000, the divs appears.

Thanks!

Comment: And how do you hide the element when the condition is not met?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its working fine for me...remove the semicolon after if block

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() > 2000){
        $('.edicao-anos').css({"display": "block"});
    } else {
        $('.edicao-anos').css({"display": "none"});  // to hide it if less than 2000px
    }
});
```